# AWS ELB rewrite http to https

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, tomcat, elastic-beanstalk, tomcat8

I am using AWS Elastic Beanstalk.  I would like to rewrite all `http` traffic to `https`.

I have the following configuration:

[image]

But if I try change the `Instance Protocol` of either of the above two to `https (443)`, then when I try access my site, it just hangs.

**Question**

How do I configure AWS Elastic Beanstalk to rewrite all `http` traffic to `https`?

Comment: You don't use the load balancer for this. You'll need to tweak the webserver config, or implement a redirect at the application level. If you're using nginx, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23709841/how-to-change-nginx-config-in-amazon-elastic-beanstalk-running-a-docker-instance - I'd imagine Apache is similar.

Comment: Or you can  use cloudfront to redirect http to https, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https.html